# A way to find a set of solutions of a matrix equal to a vector knowing only its echelon form and a vector in the original matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

After reduction of a matrix A, the following echelon is obtained:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -5 &0 &-1 &-1& 3& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2&2&0&2&0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

Third column of A is equal to $[1,2,3,4]^T$.

The question is to determine the set of solutions of $Ax = [1,2,3,4]^T$

I proceed to convert the echelon reduced matrix of A to a form where the third column is equal to $[1,2,3,4]$ and from there try to find a general solution to the equation:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -5 &1 &0 &-1& 4& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2&2&0&2&0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 4 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
x_5 \\
x_6 \\
x_7 
\end{bmatrix}
= 
 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\\ 4 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

However, I am not sure whether that is the correct solution as I have a feeling I am assuming that the matrix above is equal to the original A matrix, and that this is not the case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you work with the augmented matrix to obtain the general solution? Also, your matrix is not in row reduced echelon form yet.

Comment: It is asked to find the solution to the original unreduced matrix equals the vector $[1,2,3,4]$, not start from the augmented one directly and just write equals $[1,2,3,4]$

Comment: Row reducing the augmented matrix yields the solutions of your problem with unreduced matrix.

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3106643/265466.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I’m sure you’ve learned, the general solution to $Ax=b$ consists of a particular solution to this equation plus the general solution of the homogeneous equation $Ax=0$. Recall that the columns of $A$ are the images of the basis vectors. This immediately gives you a particular solution to $Ax=[1,2,3,4]^T$. You can also continue from the reduced matrix to the final row-reduced echelon form of $A$, from which I assume you can find the null space of $A$, i.e., construct the general solution of $Ax=0$.